# Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list

Tags: java, android, android-support-library

Хочу что бы программа работала и на ранних версиях. Добавила так же и android-support-v7, но уже была android-support-v4. Что нужно сделать что бы заработало?

```
import java.util.Locale;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private String[] mPlanetTitles;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
                GravityCompat.START);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, /* host Activity */
        mDrawerLayout, /* DrawerLayout object */
        R.drawable.ic_drawer, 
        R.string.drawer_open, 
        R.string.drawer_close 
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); 
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); 
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_websearch:
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
            intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, getActionBar().getTitle());
            if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.app_not_available,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }
    private void selectItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
    public static class PlanetFragment extends Fragment {
        public static final String ARG_PLANET_NUMBER = "planet_number";

        public PlanetFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_planet,
                    container, false);
            int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PLANET_NUMBER);
            String planet = getResources()
                    .getStringArray(R.array.planets_array)[i];

            int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(
                    planet.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()), "drawable",
                    getActivity().getPackageName());
            ((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image))
                    .setImageResource(imageId);
            getActivity().setTitle(planet);
            return rootView;}}}
```

Comment: @Imire, погуглите ваш заголовок. Если кратко, то удалите support library из зависимостей приложеиня,а  также библиотек, которые вы используете (ABS, да?), и добавьте заново.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я удалила все библиотеки, и добавила заново. Как выяснилось, support-library-v7 уже включает в себя v4.